# If MyClass inherits from ParentClass will instances created by MyClass also inherit instance properties and instance methods of ParentClass?

Tags: objective-c

If MyClass inherits from ParentClass will instances created by MyClass also inherit instance properties and instance methods of ParentClass, along with class properties and class methods, and be able to respond to messages like instances of ParentClass do?!

Comment: Have you read about Object Orientation? What problem are you having?

Comment: No problem really, I have read it but I require a definite answer to this clear question. My own answer is YES, but I need third party verification so my entire mental model (understanding) of the issue can be confirmed.

Comment: Why don't you run some tests to confirm your understanding?

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but working with one, who is unavailable now. Building a visualization for him on this simple subject. I was building a schematic view of this in Illustrator and got to this inheritance thing. Everyone talks about Classes and Instances and Class Inheritance but no "Instance Inheritance". I visualize the Class as a factory that produces Instances, many of them which then go on to interact with other Instances produced by other Classes (factories). This interaction of diverse Instances I understand is called Object Composition.

Comment: Classes are the definition. Instances are the `usable` version, a stamped out runnable copy from the definition. Instances are what Classes define, so the class defines the inheritance and the instances use that at runtime.

Comment: The way I understand it... it would be rather pointless if you didn't inherit the Instance methods and properties. Looking at the documentation right now and everyone seems to only mention the "extra" methods and properties a subclass has and it's inheritance chain. Somehow it is understood by convention that if you want to know anything about the parent classes you have to go look into them. There is no "view" showing the "actual object" with all it's properties and methods regardless of the depth of the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Indeed, this is behind the reason for OO, without this you're talking about functional programming. That kind of depends on the implementation of the language. But generally no, there is no single view as each class is a combination of perhaps several different combined definitions.

Comment: Interesting... your comment is. So what I have just described could be thought of as a "functional view" on object orientation? Did some Pascal programming in the 6th-8th grade. Would that language qualify as a functional one? I've been reading this documentation long enough to understand it wasn't Object Oriented.

Comment: Pascal is procedural, for this purpose the same as functional. Functional doesn't use objects, there are no instances, no inheritance.

Comment: WOW great... you have shed light on a very dark subject for me, friend. Everything is illuminated. May the force be with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:-

Yes, if MyClass inherits from ParentClass the instances created by MyClass also inherit instance properties and instance methods of ParentClass, along with class properties and class methods, and be able to respond to messages like instances of ParentClass.

For more refer [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please edit it and replace "base class" with "MyClass" and "base class" with "MyClass" so it is a precise answer to my question and I will accept it.